# How to decide what information should I place on the item card?

Tags: user-research, cards

Imagine you have to design an app that will help users in ordering food from the restaurants. You  make an order and go to "My orders" where you can see a list of your orders from different restaurants. You have there 2 cards with some information (restaurant title, price... something else). What research should we make in order to decide what information our users want to see first on the order cards? Interview? Card sorting? Priority sorting?

Imagine also that app's owner said "I don't know what we should put there! How do I know? I'm an owner, just do it". And you want to get some objective data and present it to him in aim to make a useful app not for owner, but for users.

Comment: I would personally include the restaurant name, the price paid, the itens ordered and the date. I usually ask behavioral questions, for example, 'what was the name of the place we orderer last week?', 'how much i owe you from that fries we ordered?' and so goes on.

Answer (score 0):

Interviews can help a little bit, but card sorting usually only captures ideas you have not ideas from the users. **Bullseye Diagram exercises** and **Rose, Bud, Thorn** are pretty good for easily getting users to brainstorm ideas and features. You'd definitely want to open with an interview or prototype testing just to form an idea of the app in the users mind first. Bullseye diagrams are always a favourite of mine, they're really easy for users to get into and start brainstorm and also easy for quadratic or thematic analysis once you have a bunch of feedback.